# Motorola Xoom bricked?

Tags: motorola-xoom

A while ago I had my Motorola Xoom (1) charging on the dock.

It got stuck at the Motorola logo screen, the first screen that appears when the tablet is turned on.

Recovery puts me at the screen showing the android lying down on its back with an exclamation mark above.

Is this solvable? Can I get the device to function again?

Note: Before this happening the tablet used to occasionally reset on its own. I think it was also heating up when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

I need some more details, like whether you are using stock ROM or custom ROM, stock kernel, etc. If you have ClockWorkMod, that will come in very handy. Devices do not usually brick without having root access first. If you have ClockWorkMod, restore your backup. If you don't, try and find your stock ROM from the Internet, although when you carry out the second method, you will lose all data on your phone (not SD card though, if it's one you plugged in manually to expand the memory).

Kind Regards,

Indraj Gandham

Comment: I didn't change anything in the table. I used it as bought. So basically I didn't root it.
And it's the first time I hear of ClockWorkMod.
But I do remember that the Android was updated to 4.0 I guess, so I think it was stock?
I don't mind loosing the data because I think I already lost it when I did a recovery.

Comment: I've edited my original answer. Unless your have an LG or Motorola phone, and have a reasonable amount of tech experience, root it, because then you can use ClockWorkMod to take what's know as a **nandroid** backup image and save it to your SD card. This is a TOTAL backup of everything on your phone.

Comment: Hold on, try to wipe you cache partition. This will not remove any of your data.

Comment: It's not a phone but a Motorola tablet.
I have Linux (and bash) experience and can follow up if someone helps since I never touched an Android on the tech level. Or maybe some links on how to do it?

Comment: Boot into recovery, and then then on "Wipe cache partition".

Comment: Speaking of Linux terminals, there are terminal apps on Google Play because Android is basically a modified version of the Linux kernel

Comment: I did a wipe cache before & just tried it again. Doesn't work. It goes back to the logo screen.
Yeh but how does terminal apps connect to the issue if I can't access the OS?

Comment: Does the device have an SD card you can take out physically?

Comment: Yeh it has a slot for a card and I already have it removed.
PS: It is a 3G/Wifi model

Comment: Okay. You have two options now. You can try to flash the **original** ROM onto your phone, or you can flash a **custom** ROM. Once you have the zip file, load it on to your SD card via your computer, and then use recovery to "Apply update". Chance of success: Custom ROM - 75%, Original ROM - 60%. Or you can take it back to where you bought the phone and they will fix it **if your phone is still under warranty**

Comment: aha, where can I get these ROM's from? Which do you suggest?

Comment: I have never had your device, lol! Sorry I can't really recommend any custom ROM. CyanogenMod, is one I recommend for any device, however! Go to [link](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) and search around.

Comment: But if you are in a bootloop, try to put your device in download mode and connect it to a computer. Then use the adb command prompt to flash it. The installer for Cyanogenmod will **not** work.

Comment: Thanks. By the way the bootloader recovery title says: Android system recovery <3e>. I guess it is not rooted right?

Comment: My Xoom also bricked itself suddenly, while playing a game it froze and it was impossible to reboot it again. Anyone experiencing bricked Xoom  may find following questions (and answers) useful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167081/fastboot-what-to-install-on-windows-desktop http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167182/xoom-images-for-recovery