# Fastboot - what to install on Windows Desktop?

Tags: fastboot, motorola-xoom

I have an older tablet Motorola Xoom Wifi (MZ 604). The tablet stopped working suddenly (while playing a game on it) and it cannot be restarted now. I have tried step described on [Motorola XOOM MZ604 hard reset](http://www.hard-reset.com/motorola-xoom-mz604-hard-reset.html):

- I have tried soft reset (Volume Up + Power), this brings the Motorola logo but nothing more.
- I was able to enter "wipe data/factory reset" option, but the reset did not finish
- I am able to enter a fastboot mode, however no matter what I have tried, I do not see any tools on the PC to connect to the device (or even to list it)

Now before I declare the tablet dead, I would like to try fix it using fastboot. What should I install on my PC (Windows 10 x64) so that I can communicate with the device?

Most guides I have seen want me to install Motorola Drivers from locations like Motorola Support, when clicking through the links, all I get are messages like  "File not found" or 404 errors. If I need any drivers, are there any generic drivers I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Driver: [Motorola End User Driver Installation](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/motorola-usb-drivers-rsd-lite-firmware-t3042687/post59139823#post59139823) - choose 64-bit.

Fastboot binary: [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=385035244224386526) - Google now does have an "official" package, but it's unintuitive to install and use, so this one is still recommended.