# Xoom - images for recovery

Tags: rom-flashing, motorola-xoom

When fixing or recovering Xoom as described in [How to Restore and Relock a Motorola Xoom Tablet to Stock](https://shoemakerbrian.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/how-to-restore-and-relock-a-motorola-xoom-tablet-to-stock/) using [fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167081/fastboot-what-to-install-on-windows-desktop/167083#167083) one needs to do following:

- fastboot erase boot
- fastboot erase system
- fastboot erase recovery
- fastboot erase userdata
- fastboot erase cache
- fastboot flash boot boot.img
- fastboot flash system system.img
- fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
- fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
- fastboot erase cache

For this one needs images `boot.img`, `system.img`, `recovery.img` and `userdata.img`. Given Xoom is old now, I have serious trouble getting those images, links I have found so far are no longer working. Are there any recent and working links, if not for stock images, then for some alternatives?

Comment: Could've just asked this along with your previous question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sticky XDA-Developers thread for that: [[INFO]Stock Images & Other Links](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1049485). I have clicked and verified that the MediaFire links are working, downloadable and contains exactly the files you wanted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I do not know how I missed this, looks fine and works for me. If the question seems to trivial now, I understand if it is closed / deleted.

Comment: Nah, I think the question itself is valid, just that you could've saved a day's worth of time by asking this yesterday. To me, more renown is always welcome ;)

Comment: As I am proceeding step by step, yesterday I did not now I will need this once I get fastboot working. ;)

Comment: Ah, that, different way of thinking and preparing, I guess. I look at guides prior to getting my devices and ready every file needed to set 'em up, if one of the files is unavailable anywhere, I'd simply give up on the device.